# Cycle and Lead time widgets in VSTS dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

For my projects in VSTS, I need to show the cycle and lead times on the VSTS dashboard. I need to customize these widgets in such a way that it shows only the time and not the graph on the widget. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very low quality post. Can you please provide an example of a widget you need to modify?

Comment: As I know those two widgets are designed as graphs, you can see all their related settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cycle-time-and-lead-time?view=azure-devops#configure-the-cycle-time-and-lead-time-widgets). Just as **Shamrai's** answer indicates, it's not possible to customize the widgets to show only the time unless you create your custom widgets.

Answer (score 0):

These widgets were designed for graphs and do not include settings for the table view. You have to create your own report with:

1. Power BI custom report ([Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops))
2. or Excel custom report ([Azure Boards and Office integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops))

Comment: Thanks Shamrai. Let me check on the reports mentioned by you.